# How to create an input validation for a division problem where i cannot input 0 in C language

Tags: c

I'm new to c language and wanted to know how to restrict the user from entering 0 as a valid number. I know you can use an if statement, but that seems too much for a simple thing. Because I recall in python being able to create validation for an input where the user cannot input a certain number.

```
printf("Input first number:  ");
scanf("%d",&num1);

printf("Input the second number:  ");
scanf("%d",&num2);
```

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated tags. C# have nothing to do with C.

Comment: As for your problem, first of all please check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Then you need a loop to ask for input again.

Comment: `do { /* get second number */ } while (/* second number == 0 */);`

Comment: So how did you do it in Python?

Comment: What makes you think that restricting user input is "a simple thing"?

Comment: an if is the simplest solution to this (or a loop's condition), what could be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

you cant prevent but you may check

```
do
{
    int scanfresult;
    printf("Input the second number (non zero):  ");
    scanfresult = scanf("%d",&num2);
}while(scanfresult != 1 || num2 == 0);
```